# Is there a trick to using Mockery in Mocha test with Typescript?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js

It would seem the usual method of importing in typescript prevents the modules from being mocked... Assume I have the following product code in a node.js project written in typescript that I would like to test:

```
// host.ts
import http = require('http');

export class Host {

    public start(port: number): http.Server {
        return http.createServer().listen(port);
    }
}
```

I have the below unit test using mockery ([d.ts in pull request #3313](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/3313)) and mocha:

```
import chai = require('chai');
import mockery = require('mockery');
import webserver = require('../hosting/host');

describe('host', (): void => {
    describe('start()', (): void => {
        before(() : void => {
            mockery.enable();
        });
        after((): void => {
            mockery.deregisterAll();
            mockery.disable();
        });

        it('should create an http server', (): void => {

            mockery.registerMock('http', {
                Server: mocks.Server,
                createServer: (app: any) : any => new mocks.Server(app)
            });
            var host: webserver.Host = new webserver.Host({ port: 111 });
            var server: any = host.start();

            chai.expect(server).is.instanceOf(mocks.Server);
        });

    });
});

module mocks {
    'use strict';

    export class Server {
        app: any;

        constructor(app: any) {
            this.app = app;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when `import webserver = require('../hosting/host')` is called the mocks in the test aren't setup yet and the un-mocked `require('http')` is returned. I attempted to try `var http = require('http')` within the `Host.start` function, but this prevents http.Server from being declared as a return value.

How should I go about implementing unit tests in Typescript with Mocks? Is there a better library than mockery that would work better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After all day of scouring the web I finally learned that: Yes, there is a trick to using Mockery in Mocha test with Typescript. The trick is using the `typeof` identifier to reference the module. I discovered this in [the Optional Module Loading and Other Advanced Loading Scenarios in this document](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript).

My updated code now looks like this:

```
// host.ts
import httpDef = require('http');

export class Host {

    public start(port: number): httpDef .Server {
        var http: typeof httpDef = require('http');
        return http.createServer().listen(port);
    }
}
```

This allows me to set up mocks in my mocha test like this:

```
import chai = require('chai');
import mockery = require('mockery');
import webserver = require('../hosting/host');

import httpDef = require('http'):

describe('host', (): void => {
    describe('start()', (): void => {
        before(() : void => {
            mockery.enable();
        });
        after((): void => {
            mockery.deregisterAll();
            mockery.disable();
        });

        it('should create an http server', (): void => {
            var mockServer: httpDef.Server = <httpDef.Server>{};
            var mockHttp: typeof httpDef = <typeof httpDef>{};
            mockHttp.createServer = () : httpDef.Server => mockServer;

            mockery.registerMock('http', mockHttp);

            var host: webserver.Host = new webserver.Host({ port: 111 });
            var server: any = host.start();

            chai.expect(server).is.equals(mockServer);
        });

    });
});
```

Some other scenarios where this can be used for dependency injection can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1478).